# Disabling id render in symfony form field

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

Is it possible to render i.e. input field without id? I am in a strange situation where I sometimes have to use two of the same forms within the same page and I cannot have two identical id's obviously. Luckily I don't really need them (no labels needed either). So is there a way to have a form fields without them? I'd like to disable them in template code if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it in your template:

```
<?php echo $form['my_field']->render(array('id' => '')) ?>
```

Or in your form class:

```
public function setup()
{
  parent::setup();

  $this->widgetSchema['my_field'] = new sfWidgetFormInput(array(), array('id' => ''));
}
```

Comment: Or you can use an option on your form to define which IDs have to be displayed